# Simple algebra, but causing arguments in a home school co-op discussion. $6^2/2(3)+4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Trying to get some human opinion on this problem.  Very simple equation, but it is eliciting quite the controversy.  I have executed it in Ruby, Java, C#, Javascript, Python, Perl and Excel with the same result, however this is being refuted as to the change of the divisor sign.  Keep in mind, these are not tech-saavy folk.

The equation:
$$6^2 \div 2(3) + 4 = x $$

Two answers so far are "58" and "10"

Please help :)

Comment: And which answer showed up when executed in those languages?  (I'm assuming it was $58$.)

Comment: $$\frac{\frac{6^2}{2}}{3} + 4 = 10,\\ \frac{6^2}{2}\cdot 3 + 4 = 58$$
It's kind of joke?

Comment: The answer that shows up consistently when I run the equation in an interpreter is 58.

Comment: Don't forget $\dfrac{6^2}{2(3)+4}=3.6$. The short version is that the written form isn't enoguh to specify a unique value; _no_ answer is unambiguously correct.

Comment: Thanks @StevenStadnicki - I think you make a great point.

Comment: order of operations specifies that multiplication is done left to right. there is always an unambiguous answer.

Comment: "I have executed it" What have you executed *exactly*? May be you show us code?

Comment: Here's a fiddle I had: http://jsfiddle.net/z5wwmLpp/

Copied this from an interactive ruby shell
`irb(main):001:0> 6**2/2*3+4

=> 58

irb(main):002:0>`

Also this wolfram alpha solution:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%5E2%2F2%283%29%2B4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of Operations dictates that we move left to right with multiplication (multiplication includes division) so we have

$$\frac{6^2}{2}3+4=58$$

No ambiguity, although it would be bad form to write an equation this way.

Answer (score 1):

[image]$6^2$ (divided by) $2(3) +4$

$6^2 = 36$

$2(3)=6$

$\frac{36}{6}= 6 +4 = 10$

The truth is that problem isn't clear. I am one of the moms from the group and my logic is that the 2(3) is implied multiplication by juxtaposition. Its not algebra (no variables)just straight computation. When I take the problem and turn it into an equation with 58 and 10 as answers and substitute 3 for x and solve for x, 10 is the answer that makes x=3.

When checking my answer, I use these equations:

6^2 / 2(x) +4 = 58 36 / 2x = 54 36 = 54*2x 36/54 =2x (34/54)/2 = x

And

6^2 / 2(x) +4=10 36 / 2x = 6 36= 6*2x 6 =2x 3=x

So, to me, that means 10 is the only viable answer.

The orignial arithmetic expression is pictured below since it can be hard to write without all of the operators available.

Comment: What equation do you get when you do the substitution?